# How do i suppress shell command output in jenkins pipeline stage view?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm running a series of jenkins pipeline commands.  I can't seem to suppress a sensitive command from both the console logs and the jenkins stage  Let's assume my jenkinsfile is something like this:

```
def silentShell(java.lang.String cmd) {
    sh('#!/bin/sh -e\n' + cmd)
}

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Write Secret Thing') {
            steps {
                silentShell 'echo "password here" > secretfile.txt'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The silentShell function successfully hides it from the console log output, but not from the stage view on the main build job page.  Is there a way to do so?

This is the bit I mean (non-redacted snippet from my testing):
[image]

Comment: Have you considered using [writeFile](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#writefile-write-file-to-workspace) instead of a shell script with echo?